# Random sample for y variable in catplot seaborn

Tags: seaborn, sample, catplot

I'm new to python and trying to create catplot (stripplot and swarmplot) with a jitter in seaborn for `x='region'` and `y='amount'` using a random sample of 300 from my y variable. I have tried:

```py
data_sample = data.sample(300)
y = data_sample['amount']

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.catplot('region', y, data=data, jitter='1', kind='strip')
```

Which produces:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Can anyone explain what this error means and how to resolve? Also, below the long list of error recommendations it is actually showing a visual of a catplot, labeled with 'Figure size 2160x2160 with 0 Axes.'

Thank you, help appreciated.

Comment: Check what the second argument to `catplot` can be; I doubt it can be a series, and should rather be the name of a column in your dataframe.

Comment: I believe you're right it can only be a column. I am going to explore Bokeh since I have a large dataset. Thx